# How can I avoid generating n^2 rows (and discarding most of them) when self-joining a table with n rows?

Tags: postgresql, optimization

Running PostgreSQL 14, I'm dealing with a table storing [ICD codes](https://www.who.int/standards/classifications/classification-of-diseases). It is just a single column with `text` values in the form `A<number>` or `A<number>.<number>`, e.g. `A4` or `A4.13`, about 50k rows in total:

```sql
create table icd_codes(code text not null);

insert into icd_codes
select 'A' || x || '.' || y
from generate_series(1, 100) x(x)
join generate_series(1, 500) y(y) on true;
```

I'd now like to generate a lookup table which maps every code `p` to all other codes `c` such that `p` is a prefix of `c`. For this to be efficient, I figured that an index would be good:

```sql
create index icd_codes_code_prefix_index on icd_codes(code text_pattern_ops);

analyze icd_codes;

explain (analyze, buffers)
create table lookup_table as
select p.code prefix, c.code code
from icd_codes p
join icd_codes c on c.code like p.code || '%';
```

I can confirm that the index is picked up for e.g. `select code from icd_codes where code like 'A04%';`, but unfortunately that last step is extremely slow. The query plan shows that a huge number of rows is discarded:

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..43751569.00 rows=12500000 width=14) (actual time=0.040..171031.597 rows=139200 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (c.code ~~ (p.code || '%'::text))
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2499860800
   Buffers: shared hit=444
   ->  Seq Scan on icd_codes p  (cost=0.00..722.00 rows=50000 width=7) (actual time=0.015..7.603 rows=50000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=222
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..972.00 rows=50000 width=7) (actual time=0.000..0.901 rows=50000 loops=50000)
         Buffers: shared hit=222
         ->  Seq Scan on icd_codes c  (cost=0.00..722.00 rows=50000 width=7) (actual time=0.006..5.185 rows=50000 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=222
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=8 read=1
 Planning Time: 0.474 ms
 Execution Time: 171094.948 ms
(14 rows)
```

I'm puzzled as to why that is - it seems it first builds 50000*50000 rows and *then* filters that based on the join condition - without using the index. I expected this to be a sequential scan over all codes, and for each a hash join using the table itself.

How could I rewrite this such that the lookup table is generated more efficiently, avoiding that a huge result set is built which then has most of its rows removed again?

Comment: Could you use a `DO` block (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) with an outer loop and then inner loops to concatenate the values together?

Comment: The efficient use of text_pattern_ops indexes requires the planner to re-write the query in a special way, which I think it can only do if it can see the pattern string at planning time.  So it needs to be a literal, or something which can be constant-folded into a literal.  You could try a gin_trgm_ops index instead, which is less efficient for prefix queries but doesn't have this limitation and so would actually get used.

Comment: @jjanes Good call - you should post this as an answer! A `gin_trgm_ops` index indeed helped a lot, bringing the runtime needed for constructing the lookup table from 171s to 6s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficient use of text_pattern_ops indexes requires the planner to re-write the query in a special way, which it can only do if it can see the pattern string at planning time. So it needs to be a literal, or something which can be constant-folded into a literal. You could try a gin_trgm_ops index instead, which is less efficient for prefix queries but doesn't have this limitation with literals and so would actually get used in this case.